# How to upload images into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, image

I created a database Table `xx_sample` and uploaded the image but it shows the image section as null

[image: Creating a Table]

[image: Get the result]

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: What MySQL version? What is the `secure_file_priv` setting (`select @@secure_file_priv`)? Please use text rather than images in SO questions.

Comment: Looks like LOAD_FILE() does not load a file. Check does your MySQL account have FILE privilege (`SHOW GRANTS;`). Check `secure_file_priv` as @danblack recommends - it must be empty string. If not then put the file into the directory set in this variable.

Comment: try to "INSERT INTO xx_sample(ID,IMAGE) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('E:/Crawling/imgs/devendra.jpg'));"